# Laravel one to one (polymorphic) not working only on specific model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am facing a super weird issue.

I have 3 tables and their equivalent model:

[image: table estructure]

App\User

```
public function company() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

App\Supplier

```
public function user() {
    return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'company');
}
```

App\Company

```
public function users() {
        return $this->morphMany(User::class, 'company');
    }
```

For some reason the relationship on App\Supplier does not work, but all the other works normal, I can even get the supplier if I have the user:

```
$supplier = \App\Supplier::find(1);
$company = \App\Company::find(2);
$supplieruser = \App\User::find(1);

$supplier->user //THIS RETURN NULL
$company->users //return collection of users normally
$suppplieruser->company //returns an instance of supplier model
```

I have tried, changing the name of the relationship and nothing.

Any idea?

Comment: Can we elaborate on your requirements a bit? Can a user belong to a company and a supplier? Can they belong to multiple companies? Can they belong to multiple suppliers?

Comment: @KurtFriars hey mate, thank u for going through my question... I found the problem, I registered a MorphMap function on the AppServiceProvider for the Supplier model... it seems it was affection the behavior

Comment: Glad to hear you solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone find this in the future... the relationship was not working because I had in my AppServiceProvider the following:

```
Relation::morphMap([
.....
            'supplier_to_supplier' => 'App\Supplier',
.....
        ]);
```

It seems that registering it here will affect all the morphs from that model.